# How to use Stripe Payment Element with subscription?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, stripes, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-payments-js

[image]
I have seen examples of how to use the Card Component alongside the Stripe API to create a customer and attach a subscription, but I do not understand how to do this with the Payment Element.

I have a React app that essentially one page has the full sign-up and payment flow. I have:

- An overview of the "Subscription" chosen
- 1 input to collect name
- 1 input to collect email
- Stripe Payment Element (Not Card Element, because I want Apple/Google Pay as well)
  *When the user gets to this page, I konw nothing about them. The only thing I know is that chose to sign up and subscribe to to a certain plan.

My basic understanding is that Payment Element needs a Payment Intent, and I don't understant how I can create one related to a subscription plan, and essentially without the customer details. Is there a way to use Payment Element, then get some sort of token and then create the customer and add the subscription? (I know you can do this with the Card Element, but I want to do this with the Payment Element ideally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at how to use the Payment Element for Subscriptions on this page : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

A high level overview of the steps are :

1. Create a customer
2. Create a subscription with `payment_behavior=default_incomplete` and you would [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) either
   [latest_invoice.payment_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-latest_invoice) or [pending_setup_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent)
3. Use
   the returned PaymentIntent / SetupIntent to initialize the Payment
   Element

Comment: I tried this but on your step 2 it seems to not let me create the subscription without a payment method. I get `This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method. Please consider adding a default payment method`

Comment: I manage to get this to work, but in step 2 I had to set the payment_behavior to default_incomplete, then I expanded the latest_invoice.payment_intent. I hope this is the correct way.

Comment: the documentation mentions that you need to use `payment_behavior=default_incomplete` but will add it to the reply for completeness

Comment: @johnnyshrewd how did you handle this issue exactly. did you find the best practice for the payment element use?

Answer (score 1):

The joys of Stripe!

Their online docs have gotten a lot better, but it's still a pile of tangled spaghetti...

In your client js code:

```
            const stripe = Stripe('{{$pk_PublishableKey}}');
            const clientSecret = '{{$clientSecret}}';

            const appearance = {
                /* appearance */
            };
            const options = {
                layout: {
                    type: 'tabs',
                    defaultCollapsed: true,
                },
                captureMethod: 'manual',   // This line is important.
            };
            const elements = stripe.elements({
```

... (a bit more code from Stripe's js example here...)

```
                // Confirm the setupIntent that was created server side:
                const {
                    error
                } = await stripe.confirmSetup({   // This is important
                    elements,
                    confirmParams: {
                        return_url: `${window.location.origin}/return.php`
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps someone miss the hours of digging in Stripe's docs.